# Register PermissionEvaluator in WebSecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Lets say I have the following PermissionEvaluator implementend

```java
@Component
public class AlwaysAccessPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject,
      Object permission) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId,
      String targetType, Object permission) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

So however I know how to register it for the Method Annotations, but I would like to use it inside of WebSecurity. So I have the following Configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Autowired
  private AlwaysAccessPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    var handler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    web.expressionHandler(handler);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/foo/{id}/**")
        .access("hasPermission(#id, 'example', 'READ')")
        .anyRequest()
        .denyAll();
  }
}
```

However when I now send a POST Request to `/foo/{id}` the PermissionEvaluator is not invoked, instead I recieve 403 Forbidden.

So how can I use my PermissionEvaluator there?

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `super.configure(http)`? It seems like you want to override the default configuration, so there would be no reason to call `super`.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Well that's due to the simplification of code for this example. Here it is not necessary, you're right. In my actual Code i'm making use of the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which has some predefined settings on `HttpSecurity`. It is also intendend to use this way: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter

Comment: It seems the issue is related to something other than the code that you've shared (perhaps the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`). Testing out the code that you shared works as expected, as long as you don't call `super.configure(http);`. You may want to update the question with the specific code that is causing the failure.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Hmm.. you're right. Sorry for wasting your time. I will try to replicate it and therfore update the question.